# Get the name of a sub-parameter, not the whole structure

Tags: ros, yaml, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a YAML file with a structure like the following:

```
field_a:
   field_a1: {field_b1, field_b2, ..., field_bM}
   field_a2: {field_b1, field_b2, ..., field_bM}
   ...
   field_aN: {field_b1, field_b2, ..., field_bM}
```

where `field_a` and `field_bj` are known a priori for all `j`, but `field_ai` are frequently changed by the user (i.e. can't be hard coded).

If I try to retieve the parameters `field_ai` using the C++ method `getParam(...)` or the command line `rosparam get /field_a`, what I get is everything in the tree hierarchy where `/field_a` is the root.

Is there a way to retrieve only the names of these `field_ai` and not their values? I could create another list with those names, but it not scale very well...

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212372/get-the-name-of-a-sub-parameter,-not-the-whole-structure/) by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2015-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to both! I did not think about [XmlRpc](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/doc/classXmlRpc_1_1XmlRpcValue.html) and the hint of using the iterator works like a charm!

This is the code for the example above:

```
std::vector<std::string> field_names;
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue list;

if (!node_handle_.getParam("/field_a", list)) {
  ROS_ERROR("Can't find '/field_a' in the YAML configuration file.");
  return;
}

for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++) {
  field_names.push_back(it->first);
}
```

For the sake of completeness `it->second` is the the nested list `{field_b1, field_b2, ..., field_bM}`.

---

Originally posted by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) with karma: 217 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can definitely try to parse this manually with [XMLRPC](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/doc/classXmlRpc_1_1XmlRpcValue.html) (or probably with yaml-cpp).

What you have here should probably be a `std::map` of `std::pair<std::string, std::vector<T>>`, but this is not supported, as far as I know.  [Simpler types work.](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists)

If you would choose python, you could use the `rospy.get_param_names()` function.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can parse the XmlRpcValue after doing getParam on `field_a`. ROS' version of XmlRpcValue adds an iterator type and begin()/end() calls, so you can iterate over a struct.

If in doubt, check the header in /opt/ros/XXX/include/XmlRpcValue.h for the API, not the official (non-ROS) docs.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-03**:
You're obviously right with checking the header in /opt/ros. I took the link which is linked from the ROS wiki Parameter Server page. Maybe we should put this note in there as well...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-03**:
Updated.            .